# ESPER - how to create a context

Tags: java, complex-event-processing, esper

I'm using ESPER 5.1.0 in java to run analysis on log events (sender, message). I want to look for certain message patterns for each single sender. 
I intend to do this by defining a [context](http://esper.codehaus.org/esper-5.1.0/doc/reference/en-US/html/context.html). I managed to create the [EPContextPartitionAdmin](http://esper.codehaus.org/esper-5.1.0/doc/reference/en-US/html/api.html#api-contextpartitionadmin) but I do not understand *how* and *where* I need to create the actual context.

Is there something like .createEPL() for a context definition? Or am I missing a point here.

Comment: no distractions, no chit-chat (read help→tour). Thanks have no place in a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes a context is an EPL construct. You declare it via the "createEPL" API.
For example:

```
admin.createEPL("create context Every5Minute start @now end after 5 minutes");
```